# Django: NoReverse Match error and page not found

Tags: python, django

I've gotten the NoReverse Match error before and I got it to work with a blind guess. and page not found I've always been able to fix so I'm really not sure what is going on.

As far as I can tell everything should be working correctly, and I even compared this code to a previous project and it looks fine (I have been tinkering with it so it may not be exactly what I originally typed in).

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Evverest</title>

        <meta name"viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="uft-8">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    </head>

<body>

    <nav>
        <div class="container">
            <a class="brand" href="{% url 'index' %}">Evverest</a>

            <div class="navbar">
                <a class="nav-link btn" href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:user-profile' %}">New Color Set</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:user_logout' %}">Logout</a>
                {% else %}
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:user_login' %}">Login</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:register' %}">Register</a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

app views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from users.forms import UserForm,UserProfileForm
from users.models import UserProfileInfo

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                                    DetailView,CreateView,
                                    UpdateView,DeleteView)

# Create your views here.
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Account now active")

        else:
            print("Login Unsuccessful")
            return HttpResponse("Username and/or password are not correct")

    else:
        return render(request,'login.html',{})

def register(request):
    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']

            profile.save()
            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors,profile_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    return render(request,'register.html',{
                                        'user_form':user_form,
                                        'profile_form':profile_form,
                                        'registered':registered
                                        })

@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = UserProfileInfo
    ordering = ['-join_date']

class UserProfileView(DetailView):
    model = UserProfileInfo

class UserEditProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = '/users_detail.html'
    form_class = UserProfileForm
    model = UserProfileInfo
```

Project urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include
from users import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',views.HomeView.as_view(),name='index'),
    url(r'^users/',include('users.urls',namespace='users')),
]
```

app urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from users import views

app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$',views.user_login,name='user_login'),
    url(r'^logout/$',views.user_logout,name='user_logout',kwargs={'next_page':'/'}),
    url(r'^register/$',views.register,name='register'),
    url(r'(?P<username>\d+)/$',views.UserProfileView.as_view(),name='user-profile'),
    url(r'(?P<username>\d+)/edit$',views.UserEditProfileView.as_view(),name='user-profile-edit'),
]
```

file structure:

[image]

**EDIT**
Here is the traceback:
[image]

Comment: Can you post a full stacktrace of the error in order to see which url causes it?

Comment: You probably need to add kwargs to the `url` tag. For example `{% url 'users:user-profile' username=user.username %}`

Comment: Also, your url pattern is for username is `\d+` which is just digits - you might have to tweak this to `\w+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: The problem come up because in another template (which I didn't post because I didn't realize it had any effect on this) I didn't put in the namespace `users`

Here is that other template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="form-base">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form action="{% url 'users:user_login' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="username">Username: </label>
        <input type="text" class="login-input" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username" />

        <label for="password">Password: </label>
        <input type="password" class="login-input" name="password" />

        <input type="submit" name="" value="Login" />
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Thank you for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

As you see in your `urls.py`:

```
url(r'(?P<username>\d+)/$',views.UserProfileView.as_view(),name='user-profile')
```

Your `user-profile` url takes one parameter, which is `username`. But in your template you do not pass it:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:user-profile' %}">New Color Set</a>
```

So Django does not know which username to pass and this causes `NoReverseMatch`.

You just need to to pass the `username` to the url:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:user-profile' username=user.username %}">New Color Set</a>
```

Comment: But there aren't any usernames yet. I was able to get it to work briefly before posting and then I switched something and it stopped working

Comment: @Garrett Since your "home" is not decorated by `login_required`, yes, you may reach a condition where there is no `user` in your context. I guess you can put an `if` block around the menu entries that need a user parameter in order to hide the menu entries linking to the profile if the user is not authenticated: `{% if not user.is_authenticated %} ... {% endif %}`. But according to your `urls.py` the 'users:user-profile' view requires an username argument so it is mandatory, there is no point arguing about it: `r'(?P<username>\d+)/$'`.

Comment: Tried that Still not sure. Added a traceback.